# How can i change the IP of assets in odoo 12?

Tags: nginx, ip, odoo, odoo-12

My IP address was changed and my odoo is working fine. But my odoo setup can't load the assets like image, CSS, JS, favicon etc. I updated the **web.base.url** also and change in **/etc/hosts**, but i am facing same issue. [image]

My current IP is http://192.58.154.46:8069/
How can i update the new IP in assets.

Comment: Can you try load with `?debug=assets` and see if it does the same? Secondly also try loading with your browser in Incognito mode and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you using odoo on localhost:

Change:
web.base.url

To:
http://localhost:8069